# Is it safe to share sensitive data in a Sharepoint through a public link with third parties?

Tags: secret-sharing, microsoft-sharepoint-online

One of the companies we're working with is sharing their user's database through a public Sharepoint link. While convenient, I'm worried that anyone on the internet can simply access the link (even though they shouldn't know about it).

Am I overly paranoid, or should we not do these kinds of things?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is random URL token secure enough for file attachments and other user content?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112021/), [Risks of sharing information just "protected" by a unguessable url](/questions/139658/), [Are random URLs a safe way to protect profile photos?](/questions/58215/), ...   In short: it is similar to having a password protected link with the same secret for each user  - and thus the possibility that the secret will leak to users which should not know it. If this is sufficient protection depends on the data.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that helps a lot, thank you.