# Does using a long, un-guessable link protect a page?

Tags: web-application, url

If I use a link like this:

```
www.example.com/vjbvhagwi74g3577384hqujvbgp39843q9-8q24380gfbqp29-q2--2=08h49h24tt982uh3...
```

Will the infomation be safe?

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: Security through Obscurity is never an option

Comment: Short answer: yes, but it comes with a few risks (e.g. browser history, logs, referrers etc).

Comment: @ScottStainton Unguessable tokens aren't obscurity, regardless if you put them in the url, a cookie or the http auth header.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I didn't read properly! I thought it was just a random hyperlink - not a token

Comment: Define safe. As far as I can see, there's no access protection so if the link is leaked anyone can view the page.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89108/is-a-website-published-in-an-obscure-directory-comparably-secure-to-being-placed

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58215/are-random-urls-a-safe-way-to-protect-profile-photos

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91837/use-of-obscure-url-for-security

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36870/is-including-a-secret-guid-in-an-url-security-through-obscurity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only access it over HTTPS, then TLS/SSL will protect the URL from eavesdroppers on the connection.

However, the secret URL can leak by other means. For example, if the page is HTML content and contains links or references to any external sources, then the URL will be leaked in the `referer` HTTP header.

Also, once the link is known it can be bookmarked, meaning there is no way to revoke access without changing the URL. If the link is posted anywhere else, it could also end up on search engines.

Finally, any directory browsing or path traversal vulnerabilities on your server could reveal the path.